# Adding and Deleting Values from Dictionary through Object Oriented Programming - Python

Tags: python, data-structures, graph, tree

I am trying to create a Python program which has the details of power grids and the houses connected to each of those power grids.

I have mainly two tasks to handle, one to add houses to the connection list of each power grid and remove them.

Following is the class for my house:

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, number, power):
        self.house_no = number
        self.power_required = power
        self.assigned_propagator_no = -1
        
    def assign_propagtor(self, number):
        self.assigned_propagator_no = number
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"house_no: {self.house_no} power_required: {self.power_required}"
```

I have a propagator class which is basically used to store all the details and connect between the houses and the power grids:

```
class Propagator:
    def __init__(self, number, max_power):
        self.propagator_no = number
        self.maximum_power = max_power
        self.power_remaining = max_power
        self.houses_connected = list()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"no : {self.propagator_no} max_power: {self.maximum_power} power_remaining: {self.power_remaining}"
    
    def connected_houses_info(self):
        for house,_ in self.houses_connected:
            print(house)
    
    # check if the house is connected part of the list or not.           
    def is_house_present(self, house_no):
        if house_no in self.houses_connected:
            return self.houses_connected.index(house_no)
        else:
            return -1
    
    # Add the house in the list.
    # Before adding check if the house is already connected
    def add_house(self, house:House):
        if house.assigned_propagator_no != -1:
            print('Already exists!')
        else:
            self.houses_connected.append(house.house_no)
    
    # Remove the house from the list, before removing need to check
    # if the house is in the assigned propoagtor list. 
    def remove_house(self, house_no:int):
        pass
```

Similarly I have created the class for my power grid:

```
class PowerGrid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.propagators = dict()
    
# Adding the propagtor into in the dictionary. 
# Check if the propagator is not part of the dictioary already
# It will not posess any value in the beginning. 
def add_propagator(self, propagator:Propagator):
    pass
    

# Removing the propagtor into in the dictionary. 
# Check if the propagator is part of the dictioary or not    
def remove_propagator(self, propagator_no):
    pass

def add_house(self, house:House, propagator_no:int):
    if propagator_no in self.propagators:
        return self.propagators[propagator_no].add_house(house)
    else:
        return False
    
def remove_house(self, house_no:int, propagator_no:int):
    if propagator_no in self.propagators:
        return self.propagators[propagator_no].remove_house(house_no)
    else:
        return False

class Propagator:
    def __init__(self, number, max_power):
        self.propagator_no = number
        self.maximum_power = max_power
        self.power_remaining = max_power
        self.houses_connected = list()
    
def __str__(self):
    return f"no : {self.propagator_no} max_power: {self.maximum_power} power_remaining: {self.power_remaining}"

def connected_houses_info(self):
    for house,_ in self.houses_connected:
        print(house)

# check if the house is connected part of the list or not.           
def is_house_present(self, house_no):
    if house_no in self.houses_connected:
        return self.houses_connected.index(house_no)
    else:
        return -1

# Add the house in the list.
# Before adding check if the house is already connected
def add_house(self, house:House):
    pass

# Remove the house from the list, before removing need to check
# if the house is in the assigned propoagtor list. 
def remove_house(self, house_no:int):
    pass
```

The main function to create the power grid is as follows:

```
def create_power_grid():
    power_grid = PowerGrid()
    
    with open('app.csv', newline='') as csvfile: # app.csv image provided later
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            
            entity_type = row['Type']
            
            if entity_type == "propagator":
                propagator = Propagator(int(row['Entity_Number']), int(row['Power']))
                power_grid.add_propagator(propagator)
            
            elif entity_type == "house":
                
                house = House(int(row['Entity_Number']), int(row['Power']))
                house.assigned_propagator_no = int(row['Assigned_Propagator'])
                
                power_grid.add_house(house, int(row['Assigned_Propagator']))
          
    return power_grid


if __name__ == "__main__":
power_grid = create_power_grid()

for _, propagator in power_grid.propagators.items():
    
    #Printing the propagator information
    print(f"Propagator No : {propagator.propagator_no}")
    print("------------Propagator Information-----------------")
    print(propagator)
    print("------------Connected Houses Information-----------------")
    propagator.connected_houses_info()
    print("\n")
    
print("----Removing House 1014 from Propagator 1002----")
if power_grid.remove_house(1014, 1002):
    print("House 1014 is successfully removed from Propagator 1002")
else:
    print("House 1014 is not connected with Propagator 1002")
    

print("\n----Removing House 1024 from Propagator 1003----")
if power_grid.remove_house(1024, 1003):
    print("House 1024 is successfully removed from Propagator 1003")
else:
    print("House 1024 is not connected with Propagator 1003")
```

I have made certain changes to the `add_propagator` function inside `class PowerGrid` as follows:

```
def add_propagator(self, propagator:Propagator):
        if (propagator.propagator_no not in self.propagators.keys()):
            self.propagators[propagator.propagator_no] = {}
            self.propagators[propagator.propagator_no]['max_power'] = propagator.maximum_power
            self.propagators[propagator.propagator_no]['houses'] = []
```

But I am getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add_house'

for the following part:

```
def add_house(self, house:House, propagator_no:int):
        if propagator_no in self.propagators:
            return self.propagators[propagator_no].add_house(house)
        else:
            return False
```

I have a CSV file from which the values are fed in. The format of the CSV file looks like the following:

[image]

I am unable to understand how to define the addition of a house and removal of a house from this, any kind of help with explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To have a key correspond to a list in a dictionary in python, note that d[item] is a list::

```py
d = dict()
for item in items_to_add:
    if item not in d:
        d[item] = []
    d[item].append(the_other_item)

# in your case:
if propagator_no not in self.propagators:
    self.propagators[propagator_no] = []
self.propagators[propagator_no].append(house)
```

Your problem is that self.propogators is a dictionary, and therefore has [these functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), not add_house.